# Time for pendulum to leave unstable equilibrium is logarithmic

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, equilibrium, stability

I would like to show that the time it takes for a pendulum to leave the unstable equilibrium at the top is logarithmic; i.e. if the starting position of the mass is $\theta_0 = \delta$ for some small $\delta > 0$, then $t(\theta = \pi/2) \sim \log(1/\delta)$ (here the angle is measured from the positive $y$-axis, so $\theta = 0$ is the unstable equilibrium point). Here's what I have so far:

Since there are no external forces in the system, a loss in potential energy is precisely the gain in kinetic energy, so
$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2 = mgh$$
where $v = l\dot{\theta}$ and $h$ denotes the height fallen. Hence,
$$\dot\theta = \frac{\sqrt{2gh}}{l} = \sqrt{2\frac{g}{l}(\cos\delta - cos\theta)}$$
since $h = l(\cos\delta - \cos\theta)$.
Ignoring constants, we have
$$\frac{d\theta}{dt} = \sqrt{\cos\delta - \cos\theta}$$
hence
$$dt = \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{\cos\delta - \cos\theta}}$$
so
$$t = \int_\delta^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos\delta - \cos\theta}}d\theta.$$
Away from $\theta = \delta$, the integral is bounded above on a finite interval and hence is finite. Near $\theta = \delta$, there are two reasonable options: the first is to expand $\cos\theta$ as
$$\cos\theta = \cos\delta - \sin(\delta)(\theta - \delta) + O(\theta - \delta)^2,$$
so the denominator locally looks like $\frac{1}{\delta\sqrt{\theta - \delta}}$ using the small angle approximation $\sin\delta \approx\delta$. This gives
$$t \sim \int_\delta^{\delta + \epsilon} \frac{1}{\delta\sqrt{\theta - \delta}}d\theta = \frac{1}{\delta}\sqrt{\theta - \delta}\vert_{\delta}^{\delta + \epsilon} = \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{\delta}}$$
For fixed $\epsilon$, this gives square-root divergence.

The other option that may be reasonable is to approximate
$$\cos\delta = 1-\frac{1}{2}\delta^2 + O(\delta)^4$$
and Taylor expand $\cos\theta$ around zero (as both $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ are small) as
$$\cos\theta = 1 - \frac{1}{2}\cdot\theta^2 + O(\theta)^4$$
then, ignoring constants
$$t \sim \int_\delta^{\delta + \epsilon}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\theta^2 - \delta^2}}d\theta = \log \vert \sqrt{\theta^2 - \delta^2} + \theta \vert \big\vert_\delta^{\delta + \epsilon} = \log(\sqrt{2\delta\epsilon + \epsilon^2} + \delta + \epsilon) - \log\delta.$$
As $\delta \rightarrow 0$, the first term is a constant $\log(2\epsilon)$, and the second term gives the logarithmic divergence.

Which of these two approaches is correct? They both seem reasonable to me but give very different divergence.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that the period diverges logarithmically?  I note that since $\sin \delta \neq 0$ so long as $\delta \neq 0$, the leading order term in your expansion of $\cos \theta$ should be
$$
\cos \theta \approx \cos \delta - \sin \delta (\theta - \delta) + \mathcal{O}(\theta - \delta)^2
$$
which (following your logic with this correction) implies a divergence proportional to $(\sin \delta)^{-1/2} \sim \delta^{-1/2}$.

Comment: I am not confident about this, but this is an exercise in Chapter 2 of Hall's "Quantum Theory for Mathematicians" and he claims the divergence should be logarithmic.

Comment: I agree that (assuming the prior reasoning is correct) the divergence seems like it goes like 
$\delta^{-1/2}$. I'm wondering though if theres an argument to the tune of taking $\delta$ small means that we should instead taylor expand around $0$, approximately cancel the first terms ($\cos\delta \approx 1-\delta$), and and we are in fact left with an integral that looks like $(\theta - \delta)^{-1}$.